# Unable to support Android lock screen widget in older version than Android 4.2 jellybeans

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Friends I want to support Android lockscreen widget. It's working on Android jellybeans 4.2. But I want to support on Ice Cream Sandwich also.

Comment: Hello Nish. I'm afraid lock screen widgets are only supported on Android 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Lock Screen widgets were only [introduced in Android 4.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Lockscreen). There is no API or support for them in previous versions of Android. You can't do this.